# JSHint how to suppress a warning?

Tags: browserify, jshint

I got a JSHint error(not warning) in my Browserify code:

```
line 1  col 200  Expected an identifier and instead saw '='.
```

Line 1 col 200 is:

```
throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND"
```

Somewhere on that `=` throws the JSHint error. However, because it was generated and required by Browserify, I cannot remove that `=`. So I was trying to suppress it. How can I do that?
I've tried to add/update/delete a lot of options in `.jshintrc`, but no luck.

Content of `jshintrc`:

```
{
    "bitwise" : true, // Prohibit bitwise operators (&, |, ^, etc.).
    "curly" : false, // Require {} for every new block or scope.
    "eqeqeq" : false, // Require triple equals i.e. `===`.
    "forin" : true, // Tolerate `for in` loops without `hasOwnPrototype`.
    "immed" : true, // Require immediate invocations to be wrapped in parens e.g. `( function(){}() );`
    "latedef" : true, // Prohibit variable use before definition.
    "newcap" : false, // Require capitalization of all constructor functions e.g. `new F()`.
    "noarg" : true, // Prohibit use of `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee`.
    "noempty" : true, // Prohibit use of empty blocks.
    "nonew" : false, // Prohibit use of constructors for side-effects.
    "plusplus" : false, // Prohibit use of `++` & `--`.
    "regexp" : true, // Prohibit `.` and `[^...]` in regular expressions.
    "undef" : true, // Require all non-global variables be declared before they are used.
    "strict" : false, // Require `use strict` pragma in every file.
    "trailing" : true, // Prohibit trailing whitespaces.
    "asi" : true, // Tolerate Automatic Semicolon Insertion (no semicolons).
    "boss" : false, // Tolerate assignments inside if, for & while. Usually conditions & loops are for comparison, not assignments.
    "debug" : false, // Allow debugger statements e.g. browser breakpoints.
    "eqnull" : false, // Tolerate use of `== null`.
    "es5" : false, // Allow EcmaScript 5 syntax.
    "esnext" : false, // Allow ES.next specific features such as `const` and `let`.
    "evil" : false, // Tolerate use of `eval`.
    "expr" : true, // Tolerate `ExpressionStatement` as Programs.
    "funcscope" : false, // Tolerate declarations of variables inside of control structures while accessing them later from the outside.
    "globalstrict" : true, // Allow global "use strict" (also enables 'strict').
    "iterator" : false, // Allow usage of __iterator__ property.
    "lastsemic" : false, // Tolerate missing semicolons when the it is omitted for the last statement in a one-line block.
    "laxbreak" : false, // Tolerate unsafe line breaks e.g. `return [\n] x` without semicolons.
    "laxcomma" : false, // Suppress warnings about comma-first coding style.
    "loopfunc" : false, // Allow functions to be defined within loops.
    "multistr" : false, // Tolerate multi-line strings.
    "onecase" : false, // Tolerate switches with just one case.
    "proto" : false, // Tolerate __proto__ property. This property is deprecated.
    "regexdash" : false, // Tolerate unescaped last dash i.e. `[-...]`.
    "scripturl" : false, // Tolerate script-targeted URLs.
    "smarttabs" : false, // Tolerate mixed tabs and spaces when the latter are used for alignmnent only.
    "shadow" : false, // Allows re-define variables later in code e.g. `var x=1; x=2;`.
    "sub" : false, // Tolerate all forms of subscript notation besides dot notation e.g. `dict['key']` instead of `dict.key`.
    "supernew" : false, // Tolerate `new function () { ... };` and `new Object;`.
    "validthis" : false, // Tolerate strict violations when the code is running in strict mode and you use this in a non-constructor function.
    "browser" : true, // Standard browser globals e.g. `window`, `document`.
    "couch" : false, // Enable globals exposed by CouchDB.
    "devel" : true, // Allow development statements e.g. `console.log();`.
    "dojo" : false, // Enable globals exposed by Dojo Toolkit.
    "jquery" : false, // Enable globals exposed by jQuery JavaScript library.
    "mootools" : false, // Enable globals exposed by MooTools JavaScript framework.
    "node" : true, // Enable globals available when code is running inside of the NodeJS runtime environment.
    "nonstandard" : false, // Define non-standard but widely adopted globals such as escape and unescape.
    "prototypejs" : false, // Enable globals exposed by Prototype JavaScript framework.
    "rhino" : false, // Enable globals available when your code is running inside of the Rhino runtime environment.
    "wsh" : false, // Enable globals available when your code is running as a script for the Windows Script Host.
    "globals": {
        "document" : true, // browser globals
        "window" : true,
        "module" : true, // browserify globals
        "require" : true
    },   
    "maxerr" : 100, // Maximum errors before stopping.
    "indent" : 2 
}
```